# Craft 3 best way/steps to create a login client area in frontend

Tags: craft3, plugins, users

I have to make a website that needs an **user area with login**.

In that area users should be able to upload to admin area or download files from admin area.

Each user has its own account that is separate from other users.

I used to work with cake framework but in the several past weeks i made a few projects in craft cms 3 and liked it due to the easy and fast time to go up and running a full stack website.

Is it possible to make the users area in the frontoffice of craft cms 3?

If it is, there is a plugin available to do it (i searched and didn't find one), or can somebody point me the steps that are needed to do it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know any plugins that do that for you since it's integrated in Craft by default. There are [Registration forms](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/user-registration-form.html) as well as [Login form examples](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/login-form.html) and you can create [Entry forms](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/entry-form.html) as well.

For gating content behind logins there is the [requireLogin](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/tags/requirelogin.html) tag which will automatically redirect you to your login route and after a successful login return to the url you wanted to visit.
Not sure what else you might need since your question is really broad.

After a registration Craft will certain system messages (utilities -> systemmessages) with activation links for their account (double-opt-in). In case a user lost/forgot his/her password you can [send them a new one](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/forgot-password-form.html) automatically.

You can check certain config values such as [loginPath](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#loginpath) or [postLoginRedirects](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#postloginredirect) as well.

Comment: it's integrated in Craft by default -> do i need craft pro, or free version will do?

Comment: You need the pro version to use it. Otherwise you would need to create all the functionality on your own

Comment: So, as i'm new to craft 3, and i need to figured if understand correctly... width craft pro, i will be able to create a cliente area (not admin area), where users can login and upload or download files previously inserted by administrators in the backoffice. Correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. They can as well create new content, new entries, categories and so on

Comment: Thank you very much.